# NebulaGraph database: How to install it on Mac book?

Tags: nebula-graph

Does any one know how to install NebulaGraph on my Mac book?

I searched [their docs](https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/4.deployment-and-installation/2.compile-and-install-nebula-graph/2.install-nebula-graph-by-rpm-or-deb/) but found only ways to install on Linux hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NebulaGraph's core part assumed it's running on Linux distros only for now.

But we could leverage virtualization tooling in macOS to do so.

Options are like

- Deploy in VMs with different hypervisors like (virtualbox, vmware player [lima](https://github.com/lima-vm/lim) etc.)
- Leverage Docker Desktop(or equivalent things like rancher desktop, then deploy it with [Nebula-Docker-Compose](https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula-docker-compose), following [this doc](https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/4.deployment-and-installation/2.compile-and-install-nebula-graph/3.deploy-nebula-graph-with-docker-compose/)

note, the link for the doc is versioned(now, 3.3.0), for future ones who visit this, please choose the latest version in the documentation version drop-down menu.