# How can I install NebulaGraph on Windows?

Tags: nebula-graph

I want to install the Nebula Graph database on Windows, but I didn't find any references. I tried install on my own, but failed in the end.

I viewed NebulaGraph-related docs https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/2.quick-start/2.install-nebula-graph/, but I didn't find what I want to.

How can I install NebulaGraph on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The situation for Windows is similar to macOS as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74711043/nebulagraph-database-how-to-install-it-on-mac-book).

We could either leverage hypervisors(WSL2, VirtualBox, VMware player, etc)/or WSL1 to spawn a Linux machine to deploy it in the VM or go with Docker Desktop + Nebula-Docker-Compose.